# jquery mistake to compare two variables

Tags: jquery

The problem to compare two variable (c and r). if c is any number <100 then everything work fine, but as soon is more than 100 it gives a wrong result.

code :

```
var c = 100;
var r = 20;
if (c < r)
{alert ('work'); }
else
{alert ('not');}
```

results:
*c=100
r=20

### not*

*c=80
r=20
work*

people put so much negative but it almost what I have but if you want to see the code :
html:

```
<script>
    var c="<?php echo $c;?>";
    var r="<?php echo $ask;?>";
    var l="<?php echo $with;?>";
</script>
```

js:

```
...
alert (c);
                alert (r);
                if (c < r)
                    { alert("unsuficient amount"); 
                    $("#din_content").load("pmt.php");  
                    }
                else
                {
                    var IDN = this.id;
                    alert("succes");
                    var b = c-r;
                    $("#din_content").load("off.php", {w_o:IDN,c:b,login:login});
                }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear and specify more what's going on?

Comment: is it comparing them as strings?  don't use var

Comment: In both cases you would get the string `'not'` alerted, because both `100 < 20` and `80 < 20` are false.

Comment: Use `console.log()`.

Comment: Is this directly from your code? Your problem and the given code don't match up.

Comment: `100` *is not less than* `20`. So what's the problem?

Comment: that is a problem that as soon it is 100 or more it give the result true

Comment: I know but it's what it give me, I don't know why it doen't work

Comment: Again, no it doesn't. The code you included *does not* give the error you suggested. It works *exactly* as it's supposed to work.

Comment: @alex_mike - you should explain [*the actual problem*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) rather than asking about the solution you've provided.

Comment: that was actual problem if you will review my edit post you will understand that is almost the same that i posted earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't replicate the problem. You should always test your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)'s to make sure they actually demonstrate the problem. It makes it much easier for people to help you and you even have a good chance of solving the problem yourself while making the SSCCE work.

You seem to be comparing strings instead of numbers, so they are being compared lexicographically, and of course `'100' < '20'` lexicographically, since `'1' < '2'`.

You should use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert your strings to numbers:

```
var c = '100';
c = parseInt(c, 10); // Convert `c` to number
```